# what functions are called when clicking on the titlebar of a form?

Tags: c#, forms, titlebar

I have a form which includes an Unity process. Sometimes "something" happens that makes impossible to perform some actions on the process. 
I discovered that clicking on the titlebar re-enables the possibility to perform the actions that i want on my process.

the "something" is my function:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myNCServer.SendMessage();
            myNCServer.SendMyObject();

            position = myNCServer.GetPosition();
            compteur++;
            unityHWNDLabel.Text = "position = " + position + " (Updated " + compteur + " times)";


        }
```

so i would like to know what really happens so that i can re-enable my process without clicking on the titlebar

or if you have any other idea on how to handle this... =)

thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private const int WM_ACTIVATE = 0x0006;
    private readonly IntPtr WA_ACTIVE = new IntPtr(1);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        things();

        SendMessage(unityHWND, WM_ACTIVATE, WA_ACTIVE, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

did the trick

thank you @Kr15

Comment: Glad to hear, could you please accept and/or vote my answer then? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying would be a dirty workaround and there may be better solutions for your problem, resp. the cause for your problem lies somewhere else and has to be handled by an another approach.

But to answer your specific question what happens when the tite bar is clicked: your program then gets a WM_NCACTIVATE message (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-ncactivate). This happens on the win32 API layer which is the layer underneath .NET. If you've never been working with win32 API you should first read about it's "message pump" mechanism (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues). You can send win32 API messages in .NET via PInvoke, there using the synchronous SendMessage() function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) or using the asynchrounous PostMessage() function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea). This should be a good entry point for your workaround.

Comment: first: thank you for your answer. And then: any idea on what may be better ?